# Can't sort query results in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to sort the following select query in ascending order by Meds_Name, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's instead sorting all the names that start with lower case letters first, and then following up with those that start with upper case.

Query works when I interpret it and execute in MySQL, but just not in Yii. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong:

```
$specs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select("im.*,m.name as Meds_Name,mf.name as Meds_Freq_name,
                            mr.name as Meds_Route_name,mu.name as Meds_Unit_name,
                            CONCAT_WS('/',im.Meds_StartMM,im.Meds_StartYYYY) as Meds_StartDate,
                            CONCAT_WS('/',im.Meds_EndMM,im.Meds_EndYYYY) as Meds_EndDate")
                ->from('indiv_meds im')
                ->leftJoin('meds m', 'im.Meds_Name=m.id')
                ->leftJoin('med_freq mf', 'im.Meds_Freq=mf.id')
                ->leftJoin('med_route mr', 'im.Meds_Route=mr.id')
                ->leftJoin('lkpmeds mu', 'im.Meds_Unit=mu.id')
                ->where($select_condition_declare)
                ->limit($limit, $start)
                ->order(array('Meds_Name asc'))
                ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the result sorting is based on the ASCII code. You can solve the problem by converting your query result sorting column to lowercase/uppercase:

```
$specs = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select("im.*, LOWER(m.name) as Meds_Name,mf.name as Meds_Freq_name,
                            mr.name as Meds_Route_name,mu.name as Meds_Unit_name,
                            CONCAT_WS('/',im.Meds_StartMM,im.Meds_StartYYYY) as Meds_StartDate,
                            CONCAT_WS('/',im.Meds_EndMM,im.Meds_EndYYYY) as Meds_EndDate")
                ->from('indiv_meds im')
                ->leftJoin('meds m', 'im.Meds_Name=m.id')
                ->leftJoin('med_freq mf', 'im.Meds_Freq=mf.id')
                ->leftJoin('med_route mr', 'im.Meds_Route=mr.id')
                ->leftJoin('lkpmeds mu', 'im.Meds_Unit=mu.id')
                ->where($select_condition_declare)
                ->limit($limit, $start)
                ->order(array('Meds_Name asc'))
                ->queryAll();
```

Comment: Thanks @Maouven. Any hints on how I can do that?

Comment: use `LOWER(m.name) as Meds_Name` as in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know much about Yii but here is what I think may help you:

```
->order(array('m.name asc'))
->limit($limit, $start)
```

"LIMIT" always comes after "ORDER BY"

---

Update:

Ok got it :)

@sharcfinz I was looking here and at this URL 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html 
they use this way

```
new \yii\db\Query()
```

for the Query Builder and I think you just mixed a little bit the Query Builder commands with the direct SQL Query command

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
```

you are using.

The "createCommand()" its used when you are going to insert an dentire SQL query command directly like

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT id, name FROM tableA")->queryAll();
```

but to use the "->select()","->order()", etc you have to use this way

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['id', 'email'])
    ->from('user')
    ->where(['last_name' => 'Smith'])
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();
```

Comment: Thanks @Elias Rodrigues! I've fixed. The problem still exists though :(

Comment: check the new update on the answer :) and let me know

Comment: Thanks for the help @Elias. I used that and the suggestion of LOWER(m.name), and that seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

change order by to,

```
->order('m.Meds_Name asc')
```